.NET 7 - Identity - The user can have just one role at time
.NET 7 - Identity
The user can have just one role at time.
After login, the user must select one roles from list to system navigation according with role selected
He can change his current role inside application, without need to logout. For example, he wants to change from "Admin" to "Common".
How get context user and change to selecte role, currently the roles are in claims to autorization
How I added roles into claims
 //dados usuario logado
 Claim claNome = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, objUser.Name);
 Claim claEmail = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email);
 Claim cla_id_token = new Claim("_id_token", _id_token.ToString());
 Claim claNameIdentifier = new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, objUser.Login);
 IList<Claim> Claims = new List<Claim>() {
      claNome,
      claEmail,
      claNameIdentifier,
      cla_id_token
     };

 foreach (var perfil in objUser.Perfis)
 {
     Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, perfil.Nome));

 }

 await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync();
 await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });

        

After that, redirect to home page. But I need to select one of Roles to user because can't show privilege of all roles, just the roles selected.
